# R programming error for prediction and error is predict.svm: test data does not match model

Tags: r, machine-learning, maxent

I tested a new data that is provided from uI, so i used new.csv file which has same column name as trained model.

What is the problem with this?

i get error in this line `classify_models(container2,maxent_model)`

```
load("maxent.rda")
new = read_csv("new.csv")
new$data <- paste(new$Title,new$Body)
new$data = as.character(new$data)
new$data = as.character(new$data)
new$data[nrow(new)] = as.character(input$caption)
new$data = toupper(new$data)
new$data = gsub("<.*?>", "", as.character(new$data))
new$data = gsub("&amp", "", new$data)
new$data = gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", new$data)
new$data = gsub("@\\w+", "", new$data)
new$data = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", new$data)
new$data = gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", new$data)
new$data = gsub("http\\w+", "", new$data)
new$data = gsub("[ \t]{2,}", "", new$data)
new$data = gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", new$data)
#write.csv(new, "new_data1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
matrix2 <- create_matrix(new["data"], language="english", 
    weighting=tm::weightTfIdf)
container2 <- create_container(matrix2, new$TagId, trainSize=NULL, 
                               testSize=1:nrow(new), virgin=TRUE)
maxent_results2 <- classify_models(container2,maxent_model)
mydata = data.frame(new,maxent_results2)
```

Comment: I think you should try a `trainSize` different to NULL. Split the number of rows in train and test for example 80%/20%. Cheers.

Comment: i changed trainsize but still it is not working

Comment: i am not giving training , i want to test only